# Get only 1 element from same element but only difference Text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code Jquery:

```
$(".health").parent(".health-container").parent(".character").children("div:contains('Main Char')")
```

Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k16tumcv/

I just want to get element `class="health"` from `class="playername-display"` that has text 'Main Char' and no success at all, tried many ways and not result as i want to. Can you find out what solution can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). `closest` traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Example (I add class after find selector):

```js
$(".health").closest("div:contains('Main Char')").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ng-tns" xpath="1">
  <div class="character-slot">
    <char class="ngText">
      <div class="character" style="border-color: rgb(30, 130, 30); border-style: dashed;">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="playername">
            <div class="playername-display" style="color: lightgreen;">
              <div style="font-size: 13px;">Main Char</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="health-container">
          <div class="health" style="transform: scaleX(1); background-color: yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </char>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ng-tns" xpath="1">
  <div class="character-slot">
    <char class="ngText">
      <div class="character" style="border-color: rgb(30, 130, 30); border-style: dashed;">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="playername">
            <div class="playername-display" style="color: lightgreen;">
              <div style="font-size: 13px;">Monster</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="health-container">
          <div class="health" style="transform: scaleX(1); background-color: yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </char>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ng-tns" xpath="1">
  <div class="character-slot">
    <char class="ngText">
      <div class="character" style="border-color: rgb(30, 130, 30); border-style: dashed;">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="playername">
            <div class="playername-display" style="color: lightgreen;">
              <div style="font-size: 13px;">Spy</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="health-container">
          <div class="health" style="transform: scaleX(1); background-color: yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </char>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ng-tns" xpath="1">
  <div class="character-slot">
    <char class="ngText">
      <div class="character" style="border-color: rgb(30, 130, 30); border-style: dashed;">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="playername">
            <div class="playername-display" style="color: lightgreen;">
              <div style="font-size: 13px;">Monster</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="health-container">
          <div class="health" style="transform: scaleX(1); background-color: yellow;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </char>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update as per comment:

Just find elements where div contains 'Main Char'.

```
$("div:contains('Main Char')").find(".health").addClass('red');
```

Comment: I tried and it selected element `class="character red"`, not `class=health`

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you for your help!